# Check if a model was modified or created on before_save event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord, before-save

I want to check if a model is being created in the before_save callback of Rails.
I also want to check if it has been modified (when updating).

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`new_record?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) to see if you have a brand new object and [`changed?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F) to see if anything has changed:

```
before_save :pancakes

def pancakes
  if new_record?
    # Not in the database yet.
  elsif changed?
    # Already exists but it has unsaved changes.
  end
end
```